# How to add indexes to already created table in Liquibase

Tags: postgresql, yaml, liquibase

There is already created table 'A'

```
'id'    'b_id'     'name'
  1         2       someName
```

Now I want to add unique index to id and b_id columns
How to do it in yml format

Comment: If in doubt [read the manual](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/create-index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on [documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/add-unique-constraint.html?Highlight=unique%20index), something like this:

```
changeSet:  
  id:  addUniqueConstraint-example  
  author:  liquibase-docs  
  changes:  
  -  addUniqueConstraint:  
      catalogName:  cat  
      clustered:  false  
      columnNames:  id, b_id  
      constraintName:  const_name  
      deferrable:  true  
      disabled:  false  
      forIndexName:    
      initiallyDeferred:  true  
      schemaName:  [yourschema]  
      tableName:  [yourtablename]  
      tablespace: 
      validate:  true
```